# Unnable to save discriminator value. (JPA spring data + hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have following situation:

Base class:

```
@Entity(name = "BaseEntity")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCR_COLUMN", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "base")
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = true,force=true)
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {
```

Subclass:

```
@Entity(name = "SubclassEntity")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
@Table(name="subclass")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "subclass_id", referencedColumnName = "base_id")
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = true,force=true)
public class Subclass extends Base {
```

Repository:

```
public interface BaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Base, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Base> {
```

The only problem I have is when I want to create a new Subclass

`repository.saveAndFlush(Base base);`

discriminator value is not saved and in DB appears NULL. I supposed it is set automatically by hibernate, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attention: see comment below (!)

---

According to http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance section "Joined, Multiple Table Inheritance":

Hibernate does not support discriminator column for inheritance strategy: joined.

Comment: These days, the comment on top of the DiscriminatorColumn annotation reads "Specifies the discriminator column for the SINGLE_TABLE and JOINED Inheritance mapping strategies," so I guess that's no longer true.